# Weird behavior when outputting integers to an Excel Spreadsheet with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, groovy, apache-poi

### Background

I am using Katalon Studio, which uses Apache POI v3.17 . I'm working on some sheet handlers, which are responsible for creating some random data records, handling those (into their collections), and once all is said and done, saving the data to their Spreadsheets/Sheets.

The Sheets work pretty much like database tables, as their records typically have some primary key, that is an `int`/`long`.

### Code

Let's look at the `PracticeModelHandler`, that I am working on, which stores :

- `practice_id` (a `long`)
- `practice_name` (a `String`)

```
@InheritConstructors
public class PracticeModelHandler extends BaseSheetHandler<PracticeModel> {

    public PracticeModel nextPracticeModel(Closure<RateCardModel> onCreateRateCardModel, Closure<DiscountModel> onCreateDiscountModel, Closure<Boolean> onCheckDuplicate) {
        return this.nextRecord({
            final Date startDate = SMDDateUtils.LastYear();
            final Date endDate = SMDDateUtils.GetEndDate(startDate, new ContractFactory().createWithStartDate(startDate).getContractTerm());

            PracticeModel model =  new PracticeFactory().createPracticeModel(
                    "Contract Renewal Test Practice - RANDOM Rate and Discount Increase ${SMDDateUtils.ToDateTimeString(new Date())}",
                    startDate,
                    endDate,
                    { Date start -> return new ContractFactory().createWithStartDate(start) },
                    onCreateRateCardModel,
                    onCreateDiscountModel,
                    );

            return model;
        },
        onCheckDuplicate);
    }

    public PracticeModel getPracticeModel(long npiNumber) {
        return this.usedRecords
                .find { PracticeModel model ->
                    return model.getNpiNumber() == npiNumber;
                }
    }

    @Override
    protected Row getRow(PracticeModel record) {
        return SMDSpreadsheetUtils.FindRowWithKey(sheet, record.getNpiNumber());
    }

    @Override
    protected String getSheetName() {
        return "Practices";
    }

    @Override
    protected void setupFirstRow(Row row) {
        Cell firstColumnDescCell = row.createCell(0),
            secondColumnDescCell = row.createCell(1);

        firstColumnDescCell.setCellValue("practice_id");
        secondColumnDescCell.setCellValue("practice_name");
    }

    @Override
    protected void extractRecordFromSheet(int rowNum) {
        Row row = this.sheet.getRow(rowNum);

        this.usedRecords.push(new PracticeModel().with { PracticeModel model ->
            model.setNpiNumber(row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue().toLong());
            model.setPracticeName(row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());

            return model;
        })
    }

    @Override
    protected void fillInRow(Row row, PracticeModel record) {
        Cell firstCell = row.getCell(0),
        secondCell = row.getCell(1);

        if (SMDSpreadsheetUtils.IsRowEmpty(row)) {
            firstCell = row.createCell(0);
            secondCell = row.createCell(1);
        }

//      firstCell.setCellValue((Long) record.getNpiNumber());
        SMDSpreadsheetUtils.WriteIntegerCellValue(firstCell, record.getNpiNumber())
        secondCell.setCellValue(record.getPracticeName());
    }
}
```

Of particular note is this `SMDSpreadsheetUtils.WriteIntegerCellValue`, which is implemented like:

```
// SOURCE: https://www.phind.com/search?cache=d4085649-039f-4d86-b5cd-963ee40bfc49
public static void WriteIntegerCellValue(Cell cell, long value) { 
    Workbook workbook = cell.getSheet().getWorkbook();
    
    CellStyle integerStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
    DataFormat format = workbook.createDataFormat();
    integerStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("0"));
    
    cell.setCellValue(value);
    cell.setCellStyle(integerStyle);
    
}
```

Under the hood, on done, we copy the `Sheet` from the sheet handler to the master spreadsheet, using the following util methods:

```
    public static Closure OnCopySheetIntoSpreadsheet(Workbook spreadsheet) {
        return { Sheet sheet ->
            Sheet targetSheet = this.OnCreateIfNotExistSheet(spreadsheet)(sheet.getSheetName());

            sheet.eachWithIndex({ Row row, int rowIdx ->
                row.eachWithIndex({ Cell cell, int colIdx ->
                    Row targetRow = targetSheet.getRow(rowIdx);
                    if (targetRow == null)
                        targetRow = targetSheet.createRow(rowIdx);

                    Cell targetCell = targetRow.getCell(colIdx);
                    if (targetCell == null)
                        targetCell = targetRow.createCell(colIdx);

                    this.copyCellValue(cell, targetCell);
                })
            })
        }
    }
    
    // SOURCE: ChatGPT AI
    public static void copyCellValue(Cell sourceCell, Cell targetCell) {
        switch (sourceCell.getCellType()) {
            case CellType.STRING:
                targetCell.setCellValue(sourceCell.getStringCellValue());
                break;
            case CellType.NUMERIC:
                if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(sourceCell)) {
                    targetCell.setCellValue(sourceCell.getDateCellValue());
                } else {
                    targetCell.setCellValue(sourceCell.getNumericCellValue());
                }
                break;
            case CellType.BOOLEAN:
                targetCell.setCellValue(sourceCell.getBooleanCellValue());
                break;
            case CellType.FORMULA:
                targetCell.setCellFormula(sourceCell.getCellFormula());
                break;
            case CellType.ERROR:
                targetCell.setCellErrorValue(sourceCell.getErrorCellValue());
                break;
            case CellType.BLANK:
                targetCell.setCellValue(null);
                break;
            default:
                // If the cell type is unknown, copy the cell value as a string
                CreationHelper creationHelper = targetCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().getCreationHelper();
                targetCell.setCellValue(creationHelper.createRichTextString(sourceCell.toString()));
        }
    }
```

### What happens when you use this code?

On the first run, it writes the data to the Sheet. However, when I go into the spreadsheet and look at it, it looks like this:

| practice_id | practice_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1.575289078E9 | Contract Renewal Test Practice - RANDOM Rate and Discount Increase 05-18-2023 08:49:53 |

**It saved my long integer as scientific notation!!**

Even worse, when I run it again, I face the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a NUMERIC value from a STRING cell
```

This is happening because of the primary key cell, which, for some reason, is being treated like a *`String`* instead of as an *`int`* (or *`long`* or *`double`*).

WHY?!

Even when I ditch that formatting hack and just write the long directly into the cell, I still face the issue!

### UPDATE to this question

**UPDATE**: The issue is happening because of my version of Apache POI (`v3.17`) using `int`s instead of `CellType`s. Changing the enum check from, for example, `CellType.NUMERIC` to `CellType.NUMERIC.code` fixes the cell type conversion issue.

The `practice_id`s are now written in the cells as thousands-separated numbers. This is a step up from what it was doing, but still undesired behavior.

Comment: can you share the PracticeModel definition calss